# How do I "append" to an immutable dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, immutability

In Scala, the [`+ (k -> v)`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html)  operator on `immutable.Map` returns a new `immutable.Map` with the contents of the original, plus the new key/value pair. Similarly, in C#, [`ImmutableDictionary.add(k, v)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466983(v=vs.111).aspx) returns a new, updated `ImmutableDictionary`.

In Swift, however, [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary) appears only to have the mutating `updateValue(v, forKey: k)` function and the mutating `[k:v]` operator.

I thought maybe I could play some trick with `flatten()`, but no luck:

```
let updated = [original, [newKey: newValue]].flatten()
```

gets me

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> FlattenCollection<[[String : AnyObject]]>' 
to specified type '[String : AnyObject]'
```

How do I create a new, modified immutable `Dictionary` from the contents of an existing one?

---

**Update:** Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24816788/27358)'s note that Swift dictionaries are value types, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052094/27358)'s mutable version, I came up with the following extension operator, but I'm not excited about it -- it seems like there must be a cleaner out-of-the-box alternative.

```
func + <K, V>(left: [K:V], right: [K:V]) -> [K:V] {
    var union = left
    for (k, v) in right {
        union[k] = v
    }
    return union
}
```

But maybe the fact (if I understand correctly) that the immutability of Swift dictionaries is a compiler check on `let` rather than a matter of different implementation classes means this is the best that can be done?

---

**Update #2:** As noted in [Jules's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347069/27358), modifying immutable dictionaries that aren't specifically optimized to share state between copies (as Swift dictionaries aren't) presents performance problems. For my current use case (`AttributedString` attribute dictionaries, which tend to be fairly small) it may still simplify certain things enough to be worth doing, but until and unless Swift implements a shared-state immutable dictionary it's probably not a good idea in the general case -- which is a good reason not to have it as a built-in feature.

Comment: Looks like someone is building a library to do just that https://github.com/tLewisII/ImStructures (Disclaimer: I haven't vetted it.)

Comment: *that the immutability of Swift dictionaries is a compiler check [...] different implementation classes* That’s wrong. Dictionaries are implemented as structs what means that they are (basically) passed by copy. Any struct value that’s stored in a `let` variable is immutable thus you can’t call `mutating` methods on it as they would change the value. If you assign a dictionary (any struct) to a `var` variable it gets copied! You then have a different dictionary with a new memory location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a good question because the answer is "you can't". Not yet, anyway--others agree this should be added, because there's a [Swift Evolution proposal for this (and some other missing `Dictionary` features)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0100-add-sequence-based-init-and-merge-to-dictionary.md). It's currently "awaiting review", so you may see a `merged()` method that's basically your `+` operator in a future version of Swift!

In the meantime, you can use your solution to append entire dictionaries, or for one value at a time:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func appending(_ key: Key, _ value: Value) -> [Key: Value] {
        var result = self
        result[key] = value
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea linking to the proposal, but `merge` isn't exactly what OP is after.

Comment: Not exactly, but it's close to what he tried with `flatten()`: it'll allow `let newDictionary = oldDictionary.merged([new: stuff])`, which is good enough for me. (Funny enough, it will also allow his existing `flatten()` trick to work.)

Comment: @jtbandes It's not, but since it's just as terse as `+(tuple: (K, V))` for single key-value pairs, it might be good enough, especially if the implementation is clever enough to be O(log n).

Comment: @andyvn22 I don't think this should be added since we are dealing with immutable data. Given this, the operation should create a new dictionary.

Comment: It does indeed create a new dictionary! As with the other collection types, this proposal will add a pair of methods, one for mutable dictionaries and one for constant ones.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do this right now. You could write your own using an extension (below).

But keep in mind that this will likely **copy** the dictionary, because dictionaries are copy-on-write, and you're doing exactly that (making a copy, then mutating it). You can avoid all this by just using a mutable variable in the first place :-)

```
extension Dictionary {
    func updatingValue(_ value: Value, forKey key: Key) -> [Key: Value] {
        var result = self
        result[key] = value
        return result
    }
}

let d1 = ["a": 1, "b": 2]
d1  // prints ["b": 2, "a": 1]
let d2 = d1.updatingValue(3, forKey: "c")
d1  // still prints ["b": 2, "a": 1]
d2  // prints ["b": 2, "a": 1, "c": 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward thing to do is to copy to a variable, modify, then re-assign back to a constant:

```
var updatable = original
updatable[newKey] = newValue
let updated = updatable
```

Not pretty, obviously, but it could be wrapped into a function easily enough.

```
extension Dictionary { 
    func addingValue(_ value: Value, forKey key: Key) -> Dictionary<Key, Value> { 
        // Could add a guard here to enforce add not update, if needed 
        var updatable = self
        updatable[key] = value 
        return updatable
    } 
}

let original = [1 : "One"]
let updated = original.addingValue("Two", forKey: 2)
```

I don't believe there's a solution other than roll-your-own.

> But maybe the fact (if I understand correctly) that the immutability of Swift dictionaries is a compiler check on `let`

Right, mutability is specified on the *storage*, that is, the variable, not on the *value*.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to update an immutable dictionary unless it has been specifically designed for immutability.

Immutable dictionaries usually use a data structure (such as a red/black tree with immutable nodes than can be shared between instances or similar) that can generate a modified copy without needing to make copies of the entire content, but only a subset (i.e. they have O(log(n)) copy-and-modify operations) but most dictionaries that are designed for a mutable system and then used with an immutable interface do not, so have O(n) copy-and-modify operations.  When your dictionary starts to get larger than a few hundred nodes, you'll really notice the performance difference.

Comment: In this particular case I'm looking at _n_ ≪ 100, but the warning is noted. From other comments/answers it sounds as if Swift immutable dictionaries have exactly this problem.