# Why is this code ambiguous?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, ambiguous

I've written this extension to `SequenceType` to mimic [Python's `collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
let input = [
    "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
    "b", "b", "b", "b",
    "c", "c", "c",
    "d", "d",
    "e"
]


let counts = input.countRepetitions()

print(counts) //expected result: ["a": 5 , "b" : 4, "c" : 3, "d" : 2, "e" : 1]
```

Here's the code:

```
extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element : Hashable {
    func countRepetitions() -> [Self.Generator.Element : Int] {
        return self.reduce([Self.Generator.Element : Int]()) { dict, element in
            dict[key: element] = (dict[element] ?? 0) + 1
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: OS X.playground:26:22: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
                return self.reduce([Self.Generator.Element : Int]()) { dict, element in
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That seems to be a restriction when defining a variable with a nested
type. While

```
let foo1: [Self.Generator.Element : Int] = [:]
```

compiles inside your method, this doesn't:

```
let foo2 = [Self.Generator.Element : Int]()
//  error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

As a workaround, you can define a typealias:

```
typealias E = Self.Generator.Element
let foo3 = [E : Int]()
```

Applied to your case:

```
extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element : Hashable {
    func countRepetitions() -> [Self.Generator.Element : Int] {
        typealias E = Self.Generator.Element
        return self.reduce([E : Int]()) { (dict, element) ->  [E : Int] in
            var dict = dict
            dict[element] = (dict[element] ?? 0) + 1
            return dict
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that closure parameters are *constants,* so you have to make
a mutable copy first. Also the closure must return a value.)

But actually you can *avoid* the problem and let the compiler infer the type:

```
extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element : Hashable {
    func countRepetitions() -> [Self.Generator.Element : Int] {
        return self.reduce([:]) { (dict, element) in
            var dict = dict
            dict[element] = (dict[element] ?? 0) + 1
            return dict
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that `reduce` creates a new dictionary in each iteration
step.
A more efficient solution would be

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
    func countRepetitions() -> [Generator.Element : Int] {
        var dict: [Generator.Element: Int] = [:]
        self.forEach {
            dict[$0] = (dict[$0] ?? 0) + 1
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

where I have also omitted the (redundant) `Self.`.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any idea why that restriction exists?

And hah please excuse the errors you address in the second part, the compiler didn't get to checking those yet xD

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Unfortunately I don't know the reason.

Comment: By the way, do you know of a way to return a copy of a dictionary which includes a new mapping, all in one expression? The dictionary equivalent to `return array + [newItem]`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: I don't know of a simple way.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Unfortunately not, [see this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38342626/2976878)